# python feature selection feature importance method from sklearn.ensemble gives inconsistent results in multiple runs

Tags: python, feature-selection

I am trying to do feature selection using python feature imporance from sklearn.ensemble. The problem is every time I run the code (below), the results varies. I mean it gives me different columns as the largest feature importance values. Isn't it strange? or am I doing something wrong (?)

I have too many features (about 500 ... & 50k records). I would like to get the more important features to improve the classification. But the results of feature importance doesn't seem consistant.

```
#Feature importance 
from sklearn.ensemble import ExtraTreesClassifier
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#X independednt cols and y the target col
model = ExtraTreesClassifier()
model.fit(X,y)

# print(model.feature_importances_)

feat_importances = pd.Series(model.feature_importances_, index=X.columns)
feat_importances.nlargest(20).plot(kind ="barh")
```

Answer (score 1):

Randomness enters the fitting, so you should not expect to end up with the exact same results. To get reproducible results, you can provide the `seed` parameter to your estimator.

If for different seeds you end up with hugely different variable importances, this means that none of the features seems to dominate the predictive content of your data, as far as trees can capture it. So variable importances should be considered with a grain of salt.

Comment: Thank you for your response. So... maybe I should post another question here... by any chance is there any method that doesn't depend on an initial set of seeds and can be used for high dimension data to extract important features for that specific dataset? how do I reduce the 500 features to something manageable so I can run clustering based on that? I did hierarchical clustering (no good 500 cols), did kmeans/medoid which are very dependent on initial seeds not to mention the number of K. Did elbow, sillouette, Affinity propagation, etc. No good results for how many clusters.... I'm lost

Comment: If your features are numerical, you could try some dimensionality reduction techniques first, say PCA or SVD. The idea is to capture the relevant variation in your data with less features. To have more guidance, I guess you should post a question in Cross Validated or Data Science Stackexchange communities with a more detailed description of your data and of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Thank you! I will

Comment: I think this answer should be accepted as it seems to answer the question :)